# Python, regex to match numbers interval

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python Re , so basically I am trying to match any number in the interval 1-99999 so I have this expression:

``\d\D|[0-9][0-9][0-9]{0,3}1 - but the downside is that it matches also one digit numbers followed by anything but a number e.g. 8r or 1"

Thanks,